# Mobile Tools or Media Queries?

Tags: theming, mobile-tools

I have always used CSS media queries on past sites for a responsive layout. Recently bumped into Drupal Mobile Tools dev.7 and liking it thus far. Trying to understand the purpose of it besides another method for a mobile site.

**CSS Media Queries:** Great if desktop / mobile sites are similar in functionality. Easy.

**Drupal Mobile Tools:** Need to load a different theme for major desktop/mobile site differences. Contextual layout. Exportable configurations.

Mainly looking for what is best practice out there. Can too many media queries put a major strain on a website with tons of hits or is Mobile Tools bit of overkill for any small/media site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using [Adaptive Theme](https://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme) or [sky](https://drupal.org/project/sky) (based off the first)? These are designed with multiple screen sizes in mind and you have a community of folks to share knowledge with.

Comment: Never have used them. Will check them out. Do you tend to stick to modules for responsive design and not media queries?

Comment: Well, you may need to open up another question. In general, AT/Sky seems to fit our needs for multiple screen sizes. It also puts a lot of the customization in admin screens vs going into CSS code.

Comment: Seems extremely handy, will definitely check it out. Thanks again for the info.

Comment: Best of luck! Also, a huge plus, AT comes out of the box with a lot of good accessibility features such as ARIA landmarks and such. As with anything, there is a learning curve but also a big ROI (return on investment).